# How to dump all Mojolicious routes?

Tags: perl, mojolicious-lite

Full Mojolicious application have `routes` command which will dump application routes:

```
script/my_app.pl routes
```

How can I do  same thing from testing script for `Lite` application?

```
use Mojo::Base -strict;
use Test::Mojo;
use Test::More;

use Mojolicious::Lite;

... # Routes defined here

my $t = Test::Mojo->new;

$t->dump_all_routes # What should I do here?
```

Answer (score 3):

A `Mojolicous::Lite` app is a fully fledged Mojolicious application, just with more convenient syntax.

- You can use `/app.pl routes` to print routes on the command line for Lite apps as well.
- You can programmatically access the routes via the [`app->routes`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious#routes) object, which is a [`Mojolicious::Routes`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Routes) object that contains individual [`Mojolicious::Routes::Route`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Routes::Route) objects.

**Unfortunately, the Routes object does not document an API for enumerating all routes.** You will therefore have to traverse the route tree yourself. The corresponding source code for the [`Mojolicious::Command::routes` command](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Command::routes) is rather convoluted. Alternatively, you can `->find($name)` specific routes by name.

The app is accessible from a `Test::Mojo` object as [`$test->app`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Mojo#app). Note that the docs for that method include a test that verifies routing:

```
ok $t->app->routes->find('echo')->is_websocket, 'WebSocket route';
```

Note that you must initialize the test object with the app name, or assign it an app instance later in order to access the app through the test object.